# Запрос данных из категории API устарел в v23

Tags: android, json

Я хочу перенести свой проект на новую версию SDK но столкнулся с старыми методами, запросами из базы данных.Помогите перевести старый метод на новый.

public void parseJSONData(){:

```
clearData();

    try {
        // request data from Category API
        HttpURLConnection client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       `URL url = new URL(CategoryAPI);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
        connection.connect();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;}`
```